# A simple copying code

Tags: perl, list, file, counter, copying

I need a simple repeating code in pearl which reads from a file lets say txt inputs the data and then saves the new data in a another txt file . The code needs to do this :

In the first txt document we have some fruits in this format

1. 2 apples
2. 3 cherry's
3. 4 tomatoes

so the code needs to do the following thing . Inputs 1. apples then it must recognize the second number which is the number of how many times it must write the word like this

1. apples -> 1-1

   ```
          apples
   ```

   2 . apples -> 1-2

   ```
              apples
   ```

after that repeat the same process for every item of the list

for code I don't have an idea how to make it I know how to input the file and how to make the  results file but that's about it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl\
open FH "<", "filename.txt" or die $!;

open FHWRITE, ">>results.txt" or die $!;

$fruit = 
 #dont know how for the $ to take the value of the first fruit 

$countnumb = split (' ',);

 # dont know how to take the second number for count number but i think its whit split 

$count =0; 

while ($count ne $countnumb)
{
    print "$fruit";
    $count++;
}

 # i dont know when this finishes how to make it go for the second fruit
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @user3523886 You might want to read this: http://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/13/perl-worst-practices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some starting point

```
while (my $line = <FH>){
  chomp($line);
  ### process the line
  #1. 2 apples 
  if ($line =~ s!^(\d+)[\.\s]+(\d+)\s+(.+?)$!!is){
    my ($line_no,$count,$text) = ($1,$2,$3);
    ### write out
    print FHWRITE $text for (1..$count); 
  } else {
     say "Cannot process $line\n";
  }
}
```